# make array index 1 instead of index 0 based

Tags: python

How can I make an array start at subscript 1 instead of subscript 0 in python?

Basically to solve this [problem](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-8G5UD6/index.html?product=EL&solution=1-8G5UD6) in python.

Comment: What's an array? What are you actually trying to do? Write python code to translate matlab to excel?

Comment: Just subtract 1 from the index whenever you access it? Either that or you could code your own list class that does it for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is going to solve an interoperability problem between Excel and MATLAB. I suppose it's theoretically possible to subclass `list` and override stuff... 5 minutes messing round with `ipython` should help. However how that helps MATLAB/Excel is unclear. Do you really need to write a file conversion script? In that case why not just use the VBA code in the page you linked to? If you do really need to write a python conversion script implementing a 1-based array is not really the right approach.

Comment: I am writing code to put a Nx1 matrix into a matlab workspace that was started using the COM. So the array will hold the Nx1 matrix numbers.

Comment: @Wooble an array is a collection of items in which the items are of equal size, and thus their index can be calculated in roughly O(1) time. Contrast with Linked-list

Comment: @Justanotherdunce: I probably deserve that response, but the point was that Python doesn't have arrays, although there are modules that provide them.

Comment: @Wooble I'm guessing the op is referring to a list, but calls them arrays anyway

Comment: Yes I would like a list that starts at index 1 instead of 0. Sorry I am used to C++ and java where they are referred to as arrays not list.

Comment: I am curious, why was this down voted almost 4 years later?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can create a class that wraps a list, and implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to be one based.  For example:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
  return self.list[index-1]

def __setitem__(self, index, value):
  self.list[index-1] = value
```

However, to get the complete range of flexibility of Python lists, you would have to implement support for slicing, deleting, etc.  If you just want a simple view of the list, one item at a time, this should do it for you.'

See [Python Documentation for Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) for more information on creating custom classes that act like sequences or mappings.

Answer (score 7):

You can use enumerate() method

```
a = ['a', 'c', 'v', 's']
for i,v in enumerate(a, 1):
    print i, v

1 a
2 c
3 v
4 s
```

Comment: Actually, enumerate is a class in module builtins, just to be picky.

Answer (score 6):

+1 to [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max). Here's something else you could try:

Just add a `None` at index 0 of your list. This should get you the functionality. You'll just need to remember to snip out the leading `None` when you pass your list off to MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom indexes of the `fidx` module:

```py
import fidx

# create custom type `list1b` from `list`
fidx.add(list, name='list1b')

# add a map for int indexes (i -> i-1)
fidx.list1b.set_index_map(int, lambda _,i: i-1, override=True)

# create your list
b = fidx.list1b([1,2,3])

print(b[1], b[2], b[3]) # (1, 2, 3)
```