# Is there a pre-defined custom indexed array in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner for python programming, specifically for scientific computing. In python, the index of a np.array, by default, starts from 0. Is it possible to change the index starting from any number, such as -1 ..., like what can do in fortran? thanks a lot.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make array index 1 instead of index 0 based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726866/make-array-index-1-instead-of-index-0-based)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Feel free to write a wrapper class that adjusts slices by such an offset.