# IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

Tags: python, numpy, index-error

Hey I am having this Index Error where I am trying to composite events but my indices start at 0 and not 1 and while have tried to do a number of things like trying to .append[i+1] I am unable to fix this error I am having.

Theres apparently something wrong with this specific line of code : `dset_IDX[offset:offset_next] = event_id[file_indices]`

While the .py file is over a 1000 lines of code so I can not show all of it I am able to show the part of the function that is giving me the error

```
def count_events(files):                                                           
    # Because we want to remove events with 0 hits,                                
    # we need to count the events beforehand (to create the h5 file).              
    # This function counts and indexes the events with more than 0 hits.           
    # Files need to be iterated in the same order to use the indexes.              
    """ This is where we manually specify the file"""                              
    num_events = 0                                                                 
    nonzero_file_events = []                                                       
    for file_index, f in enumerate(files):                                         
        data = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)                                       
        nonzero_file_events.append([])                                             
        hits = data['digi_hit_pmt']                                                
        for i in range(len(hits)):                                                 
            if len(hits[i]) != 0:                                                  
                nonzero_file_events[file_index].append(i)                          
                num_events += 1                                                    
    return num_events, nonzero_file_events                                         
                                                                                   
                                                                                   
def GenMapping(csv_file):                                                          
    mPMT_to_index = {}                                                             
    with open(csv_file) as f:                                                      
        rows = f.readline().split(",")[1:]                                         
        rows = [int(r.strip()) for r in rows]                                      
                                                                                   
        for line in f:                                                             
            line_split = line.split(",")                                           
            col = int(line_split[0].strip())                                       
            for row, value in zip(rows, line_split[1:]):                           
                value = value.strip()                                              
                if value:  # If the value is not empty                             
                    mPMT_to_index[int(value)] = [col, row]                         
    npmap = np.zeros((max(mPMT_to_index) + 1, 2), dtype=np.int)                    
    for k, v in mPMT_to_index.items():                                             
        npmap[k] = v                                                               
    return npmap
```

```
def GenerateMultiMuonSample_h5(avg_mu_per_ev=2.5, sigma_time_offset=21.2):
    """                                                                                                       
    Inputs:                                                                                                   
     avg_mu_per_ev == Poisson distribution mean for number of muons in each spill                             
     sigma_time_offset == Width of spill (Gaussian) in nanoseconds                                            
    """
    files = ['event998.npz']

    # Remove whitespace                                                                                       
    files = [x.strip() for x in files]

    # Check that files were provided                                                                          
    if len(files) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No files provided!!")
    print("Merging " + str(len(files)) + " files")

    # Start merging                                                                                           

    num_nonzero_events, nonzero_event_indexes = count_events(files)
    print(num_nonzero_events)

    # np.random.poisson( avg_mu_per_ev, number_of_throws )                                                    
    num_muons = np.random.poisson(avg_mu_per_ev, num_nonzero_events - 2954)

    # creates h5 file to generate the h5 file                                                                  

    dtype_events = np.dtype(np.float32)
    dtype_labels = np.dtype(np.int32)
    dtype_energies = np.dtype(np.float32)
    dtype_positions = np.dtype(np.float32)
    dtype_IDX = np.dtype(np.int32)
    dtype_PATHS = h5py.special_dtype(vlen=str)
    dtype_angles = np.dtype(np.float32)
    # sets h5 file to be written                                                                               
    h5_file = h5py.File('multimuonfile(2).h5', 'w')
    dset_event_data = h5_file.create_dataset("event_data",
                                             shape=(num_nonzero_events,) + IMAGE_SHAPE,
                                             dtype=dtype_events)
    dset_labels = h5_file.create_dataset("labels",
                                         shape=(num_nonzero_events,),
                                         dtype=dtype_labels)
    dset_energies = h5_file.create_dataset("energies",
                                           shape=(num_nonzero_events, 1),
                                           dtype=dtype_energies)
    dset_positions = h5_file.create_dataset("positions",
                                            shape=(num_nonzero_events, 1, 3),
                                            dtype=dtype_positions)
    dset_IDX = h5_file.create_dataset("event_ids",
                                      shape=(num_nonzero_events,),
                                      dtype=dtype_IDX)
    dset_PATHS = h5_file.create_dataset("root_files",
                                        shape=(num_nonzero_events,),
                                        dtype=dtype_PATHS)
    dset_angles = h5_file.create_dataset("angles",
                                         shape=(num_nonzero_events, 2),
                                         dtype=dtype_angles)

    # 22 -> gamma, 11 -> electron, 13 -> muon                                                                 
    # corresponds to labelling used in CNN with only barrel                                                   
    # IWCDmPMT_4pi_full_tank_gamma_E0to1000MeV_unif-pos-R371-y521cm_4pi-dir_3000evts_329.npz has an event     
    # with pid 11 though....                                                                                  
    # pid_to_label = {22:0, 11:1, 13:2}                                                                       

    offset = 0
    offset_next = 0
    mPMT_to_index = GenMapping(PMT_LABELS)
    # Loop over files                                                                                         
    for file_index, filename in enumerate(files):
        data = np.load(filename, allow_pickle=True)
        nonzero_events_in_file = len(nonzero_event_indexes[file_index])
        x_data = np.zeros((nonzero_events_in_file,) + IMAGE_SHAPE,
                          dtype=dtype_events)
        digi_hit_pmt = data['digi_hit_pmt']
        # digi_hit_charge = data['digi_hit_charge']                                                           
        # digi_hit_time = data['digi_hit_time']                                                               
        # digi_hit_trigger = data['digi_hit_trigger']                                                         
        # trigger_time = data['trigger_time']                                                                 
        delay = 0
        # Loop over events in file                                                                            
        # Loop over number of muons in each event                                                             
        event_id = np.array([], dtype=np.int32)
        root_file = np.array([], dtype=np.str)
        pid = np.array([])
        position = np.array([])
        direction = np.array([])
        energy = np.array([])
        labels = np.array([])

        # with open("ResultFile.txt", "w") as text_file:                                                       
        # sys.stdout = open("Result2.txt", "w")                                                                

        for i, nmu in enumerate(num_muons):
            # np.savetxt(text_file, i, nmu,fmt="%d")                                                           
            # text_file.write("processing output entry " + str(i) + " with " + nmu + " muons")                 
            print("processing output entry ", i, " with ", nmu, " muons")
            indices = np.random.randint(0, len(digi_hit_pmt), max(1, nmu))
            time_offs = [0.]
            if nmu > 1:
                time_offs = np.append(time_offs, np.random.normal(0., sigma_time_offset, nmu - 1))
            hit_pmts, charge, time = SumEvents(indices, time_offs, data, nmu == 0)
            hit_mpmts = hit_pmts // 19
            pmt_channels = hit_pmts % 19
            rows = mPMT_to_index[hit_mpmts, 0]
            cols = mPMT_to_index[hit_mpmts, 1]
            x_data[i - delay, rows, cols, pmt_channels] = charge
            x_data[i - delay, rows, cols, pmt_channels + 19] = time

            # fix below!!!                                                                                    
            idx0 = indices[0]
            event_id = np.append(event_id, data['event_id'][idx0])
            root_file = np.append(root_file, data['root_file'][idx0])
            pid = np.append(pid, data['pid'][idx0])
            position = np.append(position, data['position'][idx0])
            direction = np.append(direction, data['direction'][idx0])
            energy = np.append(energy, np.sum(data['energy'][indices]))
            labels = np.append(labels, nmu)

        offset_next += nonzero_events_in_file

        file_indices = nonzero_event_indexes[file_index]

        dset_IDX[offset:offset_next] = event_id[file_indices]
        dset_PATHS[offset:offset_next] = root_file[file_indices]
        dset_energies[offset:offset_next, :] = energy[file_indices].reshape(-1, 1)
        dset_positions[offset:offset_next, :, :] = position[file_indices].reshape(-1, 1, 3)
        dset_labels[offset:offset_next] = labels[file_indices]
        print(event_id)
        direction = direction[file_indices]
        polar = np.arccos(direction[:, 1])
        azimuth = np.arctan2(direction[:, 2], direction[:, 0])
        dset_angles[offset:offset_next, :] = np.hstack((polar.reshape(-1, 1), azimuth.reshape(-1, 1)))
        dset_event_data[offset:offset_next, :] = x_data

        offset = offset_next                                         
        print("Finished file: {}".format(filename))                  
                                                                     
    #sys.stdout.close()                                              
    print("Saving")                                                  
    #h5_file.close()                                                 
    print("Finished")                                                
                                                                     
                                                                     
# In[ ]:                                                             
                                                                     
                                                                     
GenerateMultiMuonSample_h5(avg_mu_per_ev=2.5, sigma_time_offset=21.2)
```

Traceback

```
Merging 1 files
2958
processing output entry  0  with  3  muons
processing output entry  1  with  1  muons
processing output entry  2  with  3  muons
processing output entry  3  with  3  muons

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abdul/OneDrive/Desktop/ISSP/ISSP-AA/TriumfCNN-AA/EventDisplay.py", line 1068, in <module>
    GenerateMultiMuonSample_h5(avg_mu_per_ev=2.5, sigma_time_offset=21.2)
  File "C:/Users/abdul/OneDrive/Desktop/ISSP/ISSP-AA/TriumfCNN-AA/EventDisplay.py", line 1044, in GenerateMultiMuonSample_h5
    dset_IDX[offset:offset_next] = event_id[file_indices]
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

Comment: Please add the error stack-trace to your question

Comment: Help us to help you. Try to remove as much unnecessary code as you possibly can, and include the missing parts for us to understand what's going on. For example, I see that the offending line uses `dset_IDX` and `offset` which aren't described in the provided code, plus `offset_next`, which uses `nonzero_events_in_file` which isn't defined here, either. At the very least, you should describe what these variables are. We are not mind-readers here (as useful as that would be).

Comment: The stacktrace mentions line 1044, but it's hard to know which one that is since we don't know the line numbers. It'll be easier to help you if you just include the line that is causing the error, with perhaps some lines around it.

Comment: @vasia the line of code is shown in the stack trace and the error code is in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

not much info is provided but what i have understood,
the error says that axis 0 has size=4 and you are trying to access index 4 which is not possible with size 4 as it starts with 0 and max index could be 3.

Comment: Yes that is correct, Sorry I am new to python and this is a assignment I am working on.

Comment: I think problem is here, file_indices = nonzero_event_indexes[file_index]    file_indices is going into event_id like         event_id[4][x], you have not posted the values  of file_indices so we cannot know what is the size of it and why it is going out of bound to 4.

Comment: so the events are coming out of a npz  file which has over 3000 events and I just made it so at the moment it only iterates up to 4 events to test my code. But, at the given moment the indices start at 0 and I am trying to make it start at 1

Comment: indices in python start from 0,insert a 0 or something before your list/array to preserve your data and ignore the 0th index. or subtract 1 from the index when passing it into event_id cause by default a list is going to start from 0 and not 1. here another way [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726866/make-array-index-1-instead-of-index-0-based